# How do I use SQL Developer for inserting and selecting unicode 7.0 values into Oracle 12.2 tables?

Tags: unicode, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, globalization, emoticons

I need to test my company's product compatibility with new features that oracle declared they have in 12.2. One of them is support for unicode 7.0.

I checked the NLS_CHARACTERSET in my database is set up to AL32UTF8, and I've got a table with varchar2 columns but I have absolutely no idea how to insert unicode values into it.

I looked at the [changeset](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/#Database_Changes) unicode published and at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129683/character-encoding/28129850#28129850) about unicode emojis and pictographs (the highest ranking answer). The problem, is that SQL*DEVELOPER (and Dbeaver for that matter) turn everything in the new languages to ? or squares and I don't know how to use SQL to insert values that will be returned as pictographs or emoticons.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is as follows:

1. Go and download [Bablepad](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelPad.html).
2. Open a new file in it and copy+paste the unicode block codes of the pictographs you want to insert into the database. highlight them and hit alt+x to convert them to the pictographs.
3. Open Notepad++ and create a new txt file with only INSERT INTO the table you created. Copy+paste the pictographs and save the file.
4. Connect to your oracle from your computer via SQL*PLUS and run @\

et voila.